# Increasing height of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I use standard UINavigationController with custom provided UINavigationBar. I cannot find a way how to expand the height of the bar, yellow area on the screenshot. Need to put a UIView on extra space.

Looks like a simple task, but after trying everything I'm out of ideas :(

Should support iOS 11+.

[image]

Comment: there is a property named prefersLargeTitle in navigation bar, check it to increase navigation bar height, and put UIImage as titleView of navigation bar

Comment: There is nothing to do around large titles, I need to expand the bar to the exact size. Putting static UIView is not a problem at all, I have updated my question.

Comment: Not sure if this is achievable using container view controller, but you can try.

Comment: Navigation bar height can't be changed. Use custom view to make your own navigation view. If needed on all screens use within a container view.

Comment: Have you tried putting a subview at a negativ y position inside the navigation bar view. You need to set clipToBounds to NO (at the parent view) for the subview to become visible outside the parent view's frame.

Comment: @D.Mika Yes, I have tried. Putting a view is not a problem at all. The problem is getting space for this view, if I just put it above title, it doesn't increase the height of the bar.

Comment: Ah ok. You can increase the height of a navigationBar. If you need space above you need to place the UINavigationController inside a custom container view controller and keep the space above the bar for the view you want to display.

Comment: @D.Mika This want to avoid as long as I can.